# Playing music notes through speaker in TASM assembly

Tags: assembly, io, tasm, speaker

I'm trying to write a program in TASM that plays music notes. I couldn't find any documentation online and the closest thing I found was [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670296/generating-music-tone-using-pc-speaker), which is able to produce a "beep" sound.
What I don't know is:

1. How this code works
2. What the sound mapping is
3. How I can play specific notes (do re mi...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing a single tone with PC speaker may use method mentioned in the quoted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670296/generating-music-tone-using-pc-speaker). It uses square-wave generator from system timer, activated by setting mode of operation  0xB6 to I/O port 0x43. See [Timer Ports](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/904-timer_ports.html).
The value 182=0xB6=0y10110110 written to port 0x43 specifies

- selection of timer counter Nr.2 (bits 6-7)
- endianess: *LowByte* first, *HighByte* second (bits 4-5)
- mode 3: square-ware generation (bits 1-3)
- format 0: binary mode (bit 0).
  Then you are expected to specify the required frequency
  with `OUT 0x42,LowByte` and `OUT 0x42,HighByte`. This 16bit binary integer number actually specifies period of the square wave, i.e. the number of ticks that must elapse to flip the wave from 0 to 1 and vice versa.

When you have programmed the frequency, ask the Programmable Peripheral Interface to connect speaker to the square-wave generator. This is done by setting the two least significat bits if PPI port 0x61, see [PPI Ports](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/906-programmable_peripheral_interface__ppi__ports.html).

```
   IN AL,0x61   ; Get the previous value of PPI port B.
   OR AL,0x03   ; Set the two least significant bits.
   OUT 0x61,AL  ; Write it back to PPI port B.
```

Now you should wait some time to let the tone play and then reset the two bits back to 0 at PPI port B.

Mapping of musical tones to frequencies you can find [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Esuits/notefreqs.html).
You will need a table to convert the frequency of *do, re, mi* etc tones to 16bit integer numbers which you will put to the system timer as *LowByte* and *HighByte*.

See [sample code](https://wiki.osdev.org/PC_Speaker) how to get  *LowByte* and *HighByte*. PC timer ticks at 1193180 Hz. When you want to play the tone *do* (note C<sub>4</sub>=261.63 Hz), calculate  1193180/261.63=4560=0x11D0. LowByte=0xD0 and HighByte=0x11.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I need to take the wavelength (cm) from your table, and round it to the nearest integer?

Comment: @ArielYael Not exactly, the wavelength needs to be scaled by a coefficient  which depends on the timer clock frequency. I updated my asnwer with an example.

Comment: I understand now, but something in the code is still unclear.. why do we use `mov al, 182`? doens't it overwrite the input frequency we store in ax?

Comment: @ArielYael Yes, it does., it's a mistake in MathAsker's code. He obviously didn't care of the exact frequency.

Comment: could you also explain please why we specifically use 182(=0xb6)?